# Binary Search not finding the middle and the second digits to the last array position

Tags: javascript

can someone tell me why my code isn't finding the middle and it isn't finding the second digit to last digit.

```
function binary(array, target) {
  i = 0;
  hi = array.length - 1;

  while (i <= array.length) {
    var middle = Math.floor((i + hi) / 2);
    if (array[middle] < target) {
      i = array[middle] + 1;
    } else if (array[middle] > target) {
      hi = array[middle] - 1;
    } else if (array[middle] === target) {
      return middle;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}

binary([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3);
```

Comment: Doing `i = array[middle] + 1` is going to be equal to the element at index `middle` plus the value of `1`. I don't believe you want to do that.

Comment: thanks! I will make adjustment.